# Not able to make video recording using playwright

Tags: playwright

I am trying playwright using python. and am not able to make the video recording.
Code is something like

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page, expect, Playwright, sync_playwright

def test_click_link(playwright: Playwright):
    chrome = playwright.chromium
    browser = chrome.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(record_video_dir="/Users/myuserid/Documents/playwright/videos/")
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://google.com")
    #some other steps
    context.close()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I am having the same issue.